# API to find bus stop latitude ,longitude?

Tags: ios, latitude-longitude

I am looking for the API which will provide me bus routes.
In general I need the API which will give me all the bus stop locations latitude/longitude by entering the source and destination.
I want the bus stop points between source and destinations.
Can anyone help me with that API?
Waiting for the API reference!
I need to use this API in iPhone.

Comment: You might be waiting a long time - there is no universal "the api" for bus routes.  What city/country do you want this data for?

Comment: I want it for the USA.I know the api which gives the bus routes by bus Id by Route Id as well.But i want the api which gives me the bus stop point between source and destination.As you can see this on many websites, on google map as well where you put source and destination e.g.

Comment: I don't know why that question was voted down.I think the guy who did it don't diserve to be good one, he must be aggressive not assertive.Well if you can't appreciate the question then don't even criticize.What did you get by voting it down.Really shame on you who did it..........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, there is no universal "the api" for bus routes.  However, Google has set up something called the [Google Transit Feed Specification](http://code.google.com/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html) which is just a spec whereby local transit authorities can make their information available to Google Maps.

Here is a list of all the US transit authorities that make their information public in this way:

http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the clarification brother.I have seen that.But what could i do ,the client is asking the same thing to do.Thats why i asked the question.Because here might be one can get help from another.Now I need to do it by some other manner.I was concerned about who voted me down.I don't know why the people do it by not reading the question properly and not understandind the situation of other.I don't think that this question is hell worst to ask .Well do good and have good...And do bad have bad..he criticized me voted down me..he will be done same by me or some other one.....

Comment: @Sabby: don't let the downvotes bother you so much (he will indeed have the same thing done to him at some point, as everybody here gets downvoted). To be fair to the downvoter, however, your question wasn't completely clear, and using a phrase like "Waiting for the api reference guys" might be interpreted as a bit pushy and rude. Personally, things like this don't bother me because I know what programming frustration feels like.

Comment: Tell your client that there is no universal database of bus routes. So unless you want to go out and collect all that information yourself, GTFS is the best option out there.

Comment: @MusiGenesis thanks for your concern.I also think that the guy misunderstood by that line.My mean was there that,if someone knows that api then let me know.Well just leave this.Surely i will ask the client for that.And again thanks for your time and concern.Now i am bit relax by your comment.thanks buddy.....

Comment: Well one thing,the GTFS data that is provided by google or other,contains the text file.Can i use those text files in my iphone app, by reading the data from the text files.But i am not sure then how to search the data in the text files.I mean then getting the points of stop from the text file by searching the source and destination.Do you have an idea then how to accomplish this functionality of finding the bus stops

Comment: I voted your answer and commment as well.......

Comment: Great answer for Google Transit Feed Specification.. Thanks.